# How to syllabify a word? Is it as per pronunciation or any other rules?

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

Is the word *critical* syllabified as **cri-ti- cal** or **crit -i- cal**. Where does the t exactly come? kindly clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Syllables are a unit of *pronunciation* so words are syllabified based on how they're pronounced. Dictionaries follow different syllabification rules, for example, [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/critical) syllabifies 'critical' as /ˈ**krɪt**.**ɪ**.**kəl**/ and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical) syllabifies it as \ˈ**kri**-**ti**-**kəl**\.

I would syllabify it the same way Prof John Wells has syllabified it in [Longman Pronunciation Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books/about/Longman_Pronunciation_Dictionary.html?id=WKIV967F1n4C&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=critical&f=false): /ˈ**krɪt**.**ɪk**.**əl**/. I'll give you two reasons as to why I prefer [Wells' syllabification](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm):

1. 'Critical' is [derived](https://www.etymonline.com/word/critical) from [*critic*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/critic?ref=etymonline_crossreference) and the suffix [*-al*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-al?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_32845), so there's a [morpheme boundary](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1475&context=edissertations) there and morpheme boundaries can override other syllabification rules, so it should be **ˈkrɪt.ɪk** + **əl** ('+' represents morpheme boundary).
2. It's not as plausible as the first reason but is reasonable nonetheless: English words don't usually end in the lax vowel /ɪ/ so there should be a consonant (coda) after it, that's why the /t/ becomes the coda of the first /ɪ/ (**krɪt**) and  the /k/ becomes the coda of the second /ɪ/ and  yields /**ˈkrɪt.ɪ.kəl**/.